# How do I grab the text of an element following the specified element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm up against multiple classes of the same name with different texts. I am trying to output a string following a class with a certain value. In the following example, I want to specify

`<dd class="value">Orange</dd>`
and return `Jim`

```
<dt class="name">Bob:</dt>
<dd class="value">Apple</dd>
<dt class="name">Steve:</dt>
<dd class="value">Orange</dd>
<dt class="name">Jim:</dt>
<dd class="value">Pear</dd>
<dt class="name">Mike:</dt>
<dd class="value">Bannana</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You tagged `beautifulsoup` in your question I am assuming you are using that. Here is a function that will achieve what you're trying to do here:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = BeautifulSoup("""
<dt class="name">Bob:</dt>
<dd class="value">Apple</dd>
<dt class="name">Steve:</dt>
<dd class="value">Orange</dd>
<dt class="name">Jim:</dt>
<dd class="value">Pear</dd>
<dt class="name">Mike:</dt>
<dd class="value">Banana</dd>""", features='html.parser')


def find(soup, fruit):
    elem = soup.select_one(f"dd:-soup-contains('{fruit}')")
    return elem.find_next("dt").text[:-1]


print(find(s, "Orange"))

# OUTPUT:
# Jim
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with

```
def find_value(soup, fruit):
    elem = soup.find("dt", string={fruit})
    if elem is None:
        'None'
    else:
        return elem.find_next("dd").text
```

just to avoid the NoneType

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is this:

1.
Import BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

2. 

Wrap all elements in `all_elements = BeautifulSoup`. Then assign a features to the whole using `html.parser`

```
all_elements = BeautifulSoup("<dt class="name">Bob:</dt>, <dd class="value">Apple</dd>, <dt class="name">Steve:</dt>, <dd class="value">Orange</dd>, <dt class="name">Jim:</dt>, <dd class="value">Pear</dd>, <dt class="name">Mike:</dt>, <dd class="value">Banana</dd>""", features='html.parser')
```

3. 

Create a function where you assign soup and fruit as parameters. The function must contain `element = soup.select_one (f "dd: -soup-contains ('{fruits}')")` to select an element.

Create a return like this `element.FOLLOWING_grab_text_element_following_specified ("dt").Text [:- 1]`, in order to fetch the text of an element following the specified element. In this row you have to use a function of BeautifulSoup called `soup.select_one`, it is used to navigate through an HTML tree using CSS selectors and to search for only one element

```
def grab_text_element_following_specified(soup, fruits):
    element = soup.select_one(f"dd:-soup-all('{fruits}')")
        
    return element.FOLLOWING_grab_text_element_following_specified("dt").text[:-1]
```

P.S: You can take a test, for example, by writing this:

```
    print(grab_text_element_following_specified(all_elements, "Apple"))
```

If you put together all the lines I wrote, you get your solution

Comment: @Zak Let me know if this code solved your question. For any help, comment me :)